# Latest library version shows image border

Tags: openseadragon

In [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgOyeX), if opened with Firefox 64.0.2 (64-bit) on MacOS, you will see that each image tile has a border. If library "2.4.0" is replaced with "2.3.1" then the issue disappears.

How to fix this?

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openseadragon/2.4.0/openseadragon.js"
```

Comment: Hmm... that looks a lot like https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/pull/1470, but that was a fix in 2.4.0! Anyway, it might be related. Perhaps you can file an issue about it? Also take a look at that issue for possible clues. You might try using JPEG instead of PNG (do you need the transparency?). You might also try using tile overlap when you create the tile set.

Comment: Sometimes we do need transparency so want to keep that option open. Strange, we have the overlap https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/imgprocuploads/tiles/b7f3a8b685f16fb88963083cfd307d32a3794ec1612f3adb0e37aa0d67ace34e.dzi

Comment: Just to connect the dots, there's more conversation on this here: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/1591